# Why does the API that obtains the archive image size for the saved game function report an error?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

I developed a game app and integrated HUAWEI Game Service. However, when I called the API for obtaining the archive image size following instructions in the documentation, the result code 7002 was returned. I cannot locate the fault. What can I do?
The relevant log information is as follows:

```
Line 560: 2020-03-17 21:12:48.436 7644-17452/? I/ServerConstant: [I/HwJOS/ServerConstant 7644:25555 :108] get DRIVE serverUrl cost:4,isEmpty:false,isChina:false, Url:https://drive-drru.cloud.hicloud.com
Line 3567: 2020-03-17 21:12:48.600 7644-17452/? I/HMSGameArchiveRequest: [W/HwJOS/HMSGameArchiveRequest 7644:25558 :172] response not GetArchiveMetadataResponse.code: 7002
Line 3568: 2020-03-17 21:12:48.601 7644-17452/? I/HMSGameHelper: [I/HwJOS/HMSGameHelper 7644:25558 :92] reportInterfaceAccessStartBIEvent interfaceName: HMSGetArchiveMaxSizeRequest.getArchiveMaxSize duration: 0 result: 7002
```

Further question: Are there any precautions for calling other APIs of HUAWEI Game Service? I also plan to use the events and achievements features of HUAWEI Game Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 7002 indicates that the server is abnormal. You need to ensure that your service location is the same as the location where your HUAWEI ID was registered.

Only devices whose service location is the same as the location where the currently signed-in HUAWEI ID was registered can call this API. To check the registration location, go to **Account center** > **Settings** > **About**. To check your service location, go to **AppGallery** > **Me** > **Settings** > **Country/Region**.

Huawei provides a full set of APIs for you to quickly implement multiple game functions. For details, please refer to the following documents:
[Events](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-events), [Achievements](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-achievement), [Leaderboards](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-leaderboards-development), [Saved games](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-archive-development), [Player status](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Guides/game-playerinfo-development).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-3-References/game-return-code-v3) you can find the list of error codes for Game service. 7002 is network error, meaning there was a problem communicating with Huawei server. Check your network and proxy settings.